# Does there exist any continuous probability density function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is increasing on $[1,+\infty)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Does there exist any continuous probability density function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is increasing on $[1,+\infty)$?

In my research I dealt to the above question and I think the answer should be negative because of the following reason:

Since $f$ is continuous then we have $f=F^\prime$ ($F$ is its CDF), Moreover if $f=F^\prime$ is increasing along with  $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$ then $F$ must be decresing and it is a contradiction with this fact that "$F$ is always non-decreasing". I am very pleased if anyone can help me.

Comment: It is not possible. If $f$ is non-negative and increasing then $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) \ne 0$, which would make the integral of $f$ divergent.

Comment: "then F must be decresing and it is a contradiction with this fact that "F is always non-decreasing"." Sorry but there is no contradiction there. Please explain why you think this is one.

Comment: @ Did, Every CDF is always non-decreasing, but here, this hypothesis makes them decreasing.

Comment: @ PierreCarre, You mean that "if $f$ is decreasing then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$"? If yes, would you prove that. thanks.

Comment: 1. Adding a space between @ and a username is a sure way that your comment is **not** signalled to said user. Is this what you want? 2. You simply fail to address my mathematical objection.

Comment: @ Did, Firstly, thanks for your useful guidance. You mean that I made a mistake in my question or I could not explain my calim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(a) >0$ for some $a$ then we get $1=\int f(x)\, dx \geq \int_a^{\infty} f(a) dy=\infty$, a contradiction. Thus $f(a)=0$ for all $a$ but then $\int f(y)dy\neq 1$.

Comment: would you tell me that "is the pdf of gamma distribution  decreasing"?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi pdf of Gamma is eventually decreasing. What I have shown is that no pdf can be increasing.